# What direction is north in the wind arrows in weather.com?

Tags: google-search

[When searching "weather" in Google, in my country Argentina,](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=weather&oq=weather&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i60l4.705j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (I hope you can access that link "as is" no matter what country are you) a weather.com special box appears on Google results:

[image: WA101963 question first example]

I click "Wind" and then a number of arrows indicating, I guess wind direction and speed are shown:

[image: WA101963 question second example]

However, the arrows, does pointing up mean north? I need a reference for that.

Comment: This really is a weather question, as the arrows are standard notation. The arrow indicates the wind direction. So the arrow pointing up would indicate wind blowing from south to north. An arrow pointing to the right would indicate wind from west to east. Checking another local weather site or on TV you should be able to confirm this.

Comment: @user3169 Is it written somewhere that standard, with a name? Is it on weather.com stated that they follow it? Thanks!

Comment: @pnuts [This is a image of "special box"!](https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.seroundtable.com/ipad-google-weather-1342615113.png) and [here are the arrows.](http://68.media.tumblr.com/7c2896ab4e04f661e54e235e22cdc07d/tumblr_n0hxcpku5u1qea4hso1_1280.png)

Comment: @pnuts Yes! It seems a great edit, easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of what I see in the [Featured Snippet](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325?hl=en-GB) from a Google Search of `weather buenos aires`:

[image: WA101963 first example]

And this part of the results from [this search](https://www.accuweather.com/en/ar/buenos-aires/7894/hourly-weather-forecast/7894):

[image: WA101963 second example]

They do not fully align (but then they are forecasts and it is weather) however should be adequate as far as determining whether `from` or `to`.

Considering 8 pm: `ESE` is [conventionally](http://www.weatherdudes.com/facts_display.php?fact_id=39) (for meteorologists) the `from`:

> Wind direction is where the wind is coming from. If the weatherman (or weatherwoman) says that the wind is southwesterly, that means that the wind is blowing FROM the southwest.

This is consistent with most weather vanes:

[image: WA101963 third example]
*[Image](https://pixabay.com/en/weather-vane-borkum-wind-figure-2772565/) courtesy of Cairomoon.*

[the head of the arrow or cockerel (or equivalent depending on the chosen design) will indicate the direction from which the wind is blowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_vane).

However, there is also a convention that for one way traffic etc any  arrow points in the direction of flow (the `to` direction) and Google (IMO very sensibly) have chosen that one. Scope for confusion is indicated (!) [here](http://www.ybw.com/forums/showthread.php?450045-Wind-Arrow-Vector-Direction-Conventions) for example.

So, from BA, an arrow this way up `↑` means the wind is blowing towards Paraguay - it's North.